# Importing .gpx/.shp file via ogr2ogr into postgis db

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gpx

I have a file with lines that make up the european coastline, and I'm trying to import it into my database. This is what I tried:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres password=1234 dbname=gisdb" test.gpx

***Between the command and the error there's a crap ton of stuff that looks like this: C5941E00209CA85032B412CD49AD2727C5941 ***

ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer tracks (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Edit: I think I should point out the file is about 6 million lines long, if that's helpful.

Result of `ogrinfo -so test.gpx tracks`:

```
ogrinfo -so test.gpx tracks
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `test.gpx'
      using driver `GPX' successful.

Layer name: tracks
Geometry: Multi Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (943609.753900, 267126.306700) - (7136351.648900, 6825119.320900)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
name: String (0.0)
cmt: String (0.0)
desc: String (0.0)
src: String (0.0)
link1_href: String (0.0)
link1_text: String (0.0)
link1_type: String (0.0)
link2_href: String (0.0)
link2_text: String (0.0)
link2_type: String (0.0)
number: Integer (0.0)
type: String (0.0)
ogr_Shape_Leng: Real (0.0)
```

Comment: What is the output of `ogrinfo -so test.gpx tracks` ?

Comment: @tilt I edited my question with the result.

Comment: It seems like your gpx file is not valid since it only counts 1 record. Would you be able to share the first 100 lines of this file? (on mac/linux: `head -n 100 test.gpx` on windows I have no clue how to do)

Comment: hope you found a solution ! I'm looking for one at the moment !